# How to do unit testing with mocks correctly

Tags: java, junit, mocking

1) I have for example the following classes:

```
Class A {
    public A() {}
}

Class B {
    private A a1;
    public A a2;

    public B(A a3) {}
    public A m1(A a4) {
        A a5 = new A();
        return a5;
    } 

}
```

I want to do unit testing on a class B. I want it to test class B only, independently of A. As I learned, I need to create a mock class for A. After this I should use it instead of A. But how do I do it without changing the code?

I have seen an example where both A and mock of A, implement a common interface, and then in class B, the interface is the formal type of the method call parameters. Is this the correct way to do it? This will help only a2,a3 and a4, but what should I do with the others?

2) How frameworks like mokito can help me? Is it worth the effort to learn how to work with them?

Comment: Definitely worth learning how to use mocking.  I wish I would have learned about it much earlier in my career than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocks, by definition, have the same type as the argument or dependency that they replace. So they are either a subclass of A (if A is a concrete class), or an implementation of A (if A is an interface).

Mocking interfaces is generaly easier than mocking concrete classes, and expressing dependencies in terms of interfaces rather than concreate classes reduce coupling, and allow for easier mocking and thus testing.

In your case, since B creates instances of A, A is of course a concrete class the method will of course return a real A instance. All the other A instances can be mocked except a1, which is private and not accessible from the outside (except using nasty reflection tricks).

Definitely learn how to use mocks and stubs. They're very valuable if you want to be serious about unit-testing.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't, because you directly instantiate an A. Mocks are for when you're injecting implementations--one reason DI/IoC are a good idea.

The more tied to implementations you are, wherever they are, the more difficult testing will be, mocks or not.

IMO mocking is a fantastic tool, and developers should be familiar with their use. They're not appropriate in every situation, but when you're developing with testing in mind, they're really useful.